# Normalize one-to-one boolean relation

Tags: sql, database, normalization

There is a large table `products`. I need to add boolean flag `disabled` to my product model. Normally I would just add a new field to existing table. But this attribute will be used very rarely, and given the number of records in the table this new field will make an unnecessary hit on performance and disk space.

So I decided to do a kind of 1NF normalization for one-to-one relation (i.e. move this field to another table having foreign key referencing `products`; I don't know if it's really 1NF — this is a part of my question). But I don't actually need `true` and `false` values for each product's `disabled` attribute, because this implies that relation's table size will equal to the size of `products`. So there's no need in relation table's value field. So my schema is:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR
);

CREATE TABLE disabled_products (
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT fk_product FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f2afc/2) to fiddle around).

Thus I receive exactly what I wanted - the value is stored only for those rare cases when the flag is set. Behind the scenes the flag is represented not by table column, but by very presence of a record in `disabled_products` for a given product.

Just want to know if I am doing right.

What are possible drawbacks of such design, if any?

Does it fit to relational model (by **it** I mean this way of normalization in general and a table consisting of single foreign key column in particular)? And if yes, how do you call this solution in terms of RDB science?

Comment: This is not denormalization.

Comment: @ypercube, Jon Hanna who edited my question, thinks it is. I thought it was normalization.

Comment: Yes, I hadn't noticed the edits. It's rolled back now in your original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People often ask themselves if they should split a table or just create one large table. I'll speak to the general logic at the bottom. In your case it's purely a well defined performance calculation.

**Pros & Cons of your solution**
1) CON: Even though records are rarely disabled you'll need to LEFT JOIN this table to every query that needs active records.

2) CON: The space savings is 1 byte which is most likely negligible, so why bother.

3) PRO: It saves you from having to alter a table which may be a problem for you.

**Recommendation:** Given the above pros and cons, I'd recommend just adding a field to your table. It's just a byte.

In general, people split their tables vertically when it is impractical to even modify a table or when there are different classes of records that each need a specific set of fields, or when for performance reasons they want to partition their table.

Comment: Thanks! Another *contra* which was the only I could think of is relative difficulty of implementation. It's very easy to add a new field to ActiveRecord model, but not so easy to implement this bizzare normalization. You gave me more reasons to abstain from it, so I guess I'll go with regular field.

Comment: It's strange that you have 2) as a CON, while it is a PRO. It saves one byte. Whether it's worth it or not, that's another matter.

Comment: It only saves a byte if the OP doesn't have a bit column already.  If he does, it goes into the same byte.

Answer (score 1):

The possible drawbacks are obvious - in contrast to storing it as a column value, you can not assume every row has a `disabled` value (so you have to apply some custom logic) and you cannot inner join the two tables because the smaller table would reduce your result set significantly. Also, the additional table does not contain any significant information but stating the disable-state and is therefore purely redundant, but in terms of "redundancy in favor of performance" I feel somehow reminded of a star schema (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema).

Comment: The additional table does contain information: "whether a product is disabled".

Comment: It has 1 bit of information in every row, so how can it be purely redundant?